# Redis retuning null value even though the key is present sometimes

Tags: spring, caching, redis, amazon-elasticache, redisson

I am using AWS Elasticache Redis cluster with Clustered mode enabled.
My current cluster configuration is having 1 node group & 2 nodes within the group. As good as having 1 master and 2 slave nodes.

I am using redisTemplate to perform the cache operation like below:

```
redisTample.execute(new SessionCallback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void execute(RedisOperations ops) {
         ops.opsForValue().set(key, Object, TTL, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         //verify that the key is created or not
         if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(ops.hasKey(key)) { 
             logger.info("Key is present. In slot: {}", redissonClient.getKeys().getSlot(key));
         }
    }
});
```

Once the above code gets executed, I see the log line Key is present with the slot information.
And then when I try to check the value of this key, the value is null sometimes!

```
Object obj = ops.opsForValue().get(key); //obj is null here
```

Note: It does not return NULL value always.
Can someone help me here what is going on?

I am trying to add the key-value to redis cache, but the value is coming as null sometimes.